# Trying to use Block Erupters with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: miner-configuration, cgminer, mining-setup

I'm trying to Mine with ASICMiner's Block Erupters on Ubuntu 13.04. I've installed everything (bitcoin-qt, cgminer, bfgminer, I've got the block erupters in usb hubs hooked up to my ubuntu box).

But neither CGMiner, nor BFGMiner detect the block erupters...

When I go to /dev I see 18 ttyUSB[0-17] devices, I guess that's probably them, but I don't really know how to tell if my system can even see them.

I have the hubs they're plugged into hooked up to another usb hub so that you've got the first hub coming out of one usb port from the box and the ANKER hubs that hold the block erupters are both hooked up to that. I don't know if that's messing it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to determine if they're being detected properly, use the 'lsusb' command.

Here's what they should look like if your system is detecting them properly (I run mine in a VM running Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo lsusb
[sudo] password for majorminer:
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
```

Make sure they're detected by the miner by using `sudo bfgminer -S all -d?` -- I found this to be a lot better on linux than cgminer.

Then start your miner with `sudo bfgminer -o $pool.goes.here -u $USER -p $PASSWORD -S all`

Comment: Great, wow you saved my butt. Turns out the command I needed was sudo bfgminer -S all.